# Include another CMake Project as Library

Tags: c++, c, qt4, cmake, kdevelop

I have decided to make a C++-Qt-GUI for a C program (both languages I don’t know), using KDevelop, which in turn uses CMake.

The C source has no header, so I made one, and migrated some structs into it, as well as the declaration of the only function in the C source i need to call.

The problem is that I can’t call it, because either CMake doesn’t find the C file (and hence the definition), or, when I add the C source to my source set in the CMakeLists.txt, it complains that both my main.cpp and the C source file have main functions.

How do I tell CMake that it should only make the function from the C file available which I declared in the header?

here is it:

```
project(oregengui)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${QT_INCLUDES} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

set(oregengui_SRCS oregengui.cpp main.cpp qrangeslider/qrangeslider.cpp)
#as soon as i add oregengui/oregengui.c, it won’t work because of the main function
qt4_automoc(${oregengui_SRCS})
add_executable(oregengui ${oregengui_SRCS})
target_link_libraries(oregengui ${QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY} ${QT_QTGUI_LIBRARY})
```

PS: I don’t want to change the C source too much, since it is a independant project. I guess the developer will accept the introduction of the header, but not much more.

Comment: Could you paste your `CMakeLists.txt` so we can work on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit rusty on this, but could you do something along the lines of:

In oregengui.c

```
#if !defined MYGUIPROJ
int main() {
...
}
#endif
```

In your CMakeLists that you want both in:

```
add_definitions( -DMYGUIPROJ )
```

The compiler should then ignore your second main function.

Comment: Maciek’s and your answer were the solution!

Answer (score 2):

Try compiling C file as library and linking it with executable.

```
add_library(clib oregengui/oregengui.c)
[...]
add_executable(oregengui ${oregengui_SRCS})
target_link_libraries(oregengui ${QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY} ${QT_QTGUI_LIBRARY} clib)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program cannot contain two main functions at the same time. Just try to rename the main function in the C file you included to your project. This is not a big change to the source, but you will have to do it locally.

Comment: But then the C project won’t compile into an executable anymore, since it doesn’t have a main function…

Comment: Just add the C file as part of your executable, and rename its main function to dummy_main, for instance. You will be able to use that function from your main, or from your Qt stuff.

Comment: I know, but I only want to refactor the C file, so that it compiles both as standalone and as part of my project, without changing anything.

Comment: You can't. You need to have only one main function in your executable. If you don't want to modify the C file, then you have to check Arun answer about creating a new process.

Answer (score 0):

if your C program has a main function, then it can be executed independently. So why not use the [QProcess::execute()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qprocess.html#execute) method to invoke the application from qt and get the output?

Comment: I don’t even use the output. On the other hand, it isn’t very elegant, since i need the structures from the C header anyway, and I figured that using a function wouldn’t very far from there.